# Make uneditable EditText respond to first click

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a popup menu appear when the user clicks on an EditText but I don't want the EditText itself to be editable.  I've tried many things like setting its `KeyListener` to null, setting it's `InputType` to null, but what always happens is that the first click gives the View focus and the second click actually registers with my OnClickListener.  So user has to click twice to get the menu to popup.  Any ideas?

```
public class PopupEditText extends EditText implements OnClickListener
{
    private PopupMenu mMenu;
    private Context   mContext;

    public PopupEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public PopupEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public PopupEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        setKeyListener(null);
        mMenu = new PopupMenu(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        mMenu.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off. I'd recommend just overriding `onTouchEvent()` directly, and responding only to `ACTION_UP` events. Optionally, force it to be disabled and non-focusable. For example:

```
public class UnmodifiableEditText extends EditText {
    private PopupMenu mPopupMenu;

    public UnmodifiableEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public UnmodifiableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public UnmodifiableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context ctx) {
        super.setEnabled(false);
        super.setFocusable(false);
        mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(ctx, this);
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing Popup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPopupMenu.show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        // Do not allow enabling the EditText
    }

    @Override public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
        // Do not allow focusability changes
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well except now the displayed text is grayed out because I set it to disabled.  Any idea what to override to fix that?

Comment: Don't set it to disabled? If the intent is that it is not editable, it seems like better UX to let it be clear that it is not editable.